# Find a conformal mapping to map the intersection of the disks $|z|<1$ and $|z-1|<1$ to the unit disk $|w|<1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

My thinking is to use a composition of mappings to map 1) the given intersection to a sector of the complex plane enclosed by two rays from the origin, 2) the sector to the upper half plane, and 3) the upper half-plane to the unit disk.

To achieve 1), I used 
$$
s(z) = \frac{z(1-i\sqrt{3})+i\sqrt{3} + 1}{z(1+i\sqrt{3})-i\sqrt{3} + 1}
$$
which maps the area conformally to all complex numbers $w$ such that $0 \leq \arg(w) \leq \frac{2\pi}{3}$.

For 2),
$$
f(z) = z^{2/3}
$$
to map to the upper half imaginary plane. To get 3), I used
$$
g(z) = \frac{z-i}{z+i}
$$
to map the upper half imaginary plane to the unit disk. I then claim that
$$
T := (g \circ f \circ s)
$$
gives us the desired mapping.

Firstly, does this look correct to others? Secondly, is there a faster way to achieve this without using a composition of 3 mappings?

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct. If your computations are correct, and you have that the argument is between $0$ to $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, then the mapping should be:

$$ f(z) = z^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

Then you will map that region to the upper complex plane. Why ? because the powers are multiplied by the argument in the complex exponential and then it cancels out the $\frac{2}{3}$.

And there is no shortcut for this. You should do all these three mappings. I usually do 4, because I never memorize the Cayley and I just rotate and then transform to the unit disk by $f(z) = \frac{z-1}{z+1}$